# Accessing the Object from within the listener

Tags: java, event-handling, event-listener, final

Let's say we have something like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setOnSomethingListener(new EventListener(){
  public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    // ...
  }
});
```

Let's say I want to access `foo` from within the Listener without making it final. Is that in any way possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a class member, i.e. define ot in the class and not in a method.
I'm unsure of why you don't want to declare it final, though.

Comment: Because I will need to call that same listener for different Images. Those are saved in a final 2d array, although the individual Images should not be final as they each need to have a unique hashcode for me to manage to find what its coordinates are. With final values this has proven impossible to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
Foo[] foo = {new Foo()};
foo.setOnSomethingListener(new EventListener(){
  public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    foo[0].doStuff();
  }
});
```